# fixes excel to latex = Undefined control sequence. ...ecto\\ para cada integrante\end{tabular}}}

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass\[xcolor=table\]{beamer}% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. 
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllll}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Numero de Actividad}}                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 1}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 2}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 3}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 4}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 5}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 6}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 7}}                                                                                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 8}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 9}}        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 10}}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 11}}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 12}}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 13}}       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{semana 14}}                                                             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Asignacion de Proyecto}}                                                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}1er Parcial}                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}\[c\]{@{}l@{}}Asignacion de proyecto\\  para cada integrante\end{tabular}}}               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}Entrega de Avance}                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}\[c\]{@{}l@{}}Investigacion previa \\  acerca del tema\end{tabular}}}                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}}                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}\[c\]{@{}l@{}}Investigacion previa \\  al marco teórico\end{tabular}}}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}\[c\]{@{}l@{}}Investigacion para \\ materiales de adquisicion\end{tabular}}}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}\[c\]{@{}l@{}}Investigacion para los \\ \\ juegos de niños\end{tabular}}}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}\begin{tabular}\[c\]{@{}l@{}}2do\\  Parcial\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}\[c\]{@{}l@{}}Investigación complementaria: \\ asesorías de psicología.\end{tabular}}}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}Entrega de Avance}                                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{2do Cuatrimestre}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Investigacion acerca de justmind protptyper}}                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}}                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}\[c\]{@{}l@{}}Investigación de páginas\\ web, blogs,páginas de juego, etc.\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}1er Parcial}}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Estructura de la página web}}                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}}                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \cline{1-7} \cline{9-15} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Asesoría con psicóloga}}                                                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}\begin{tabular}\[c\]{@{}l@{}}Entrega \\ de \\ Avance\end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Investigación para complementar}}                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Investigación para página de apoyo}}                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}2do Parcial}                                            \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}\[c\]{@{}l@{}}Asesorias para realizar \\ programas\\ (Juegos Didacticos)\end{tabular}}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}Entrega de Avance}                                      \\ \hline
                                                                                                                                    &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                                                                                                                &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                               &                                                                                                     \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}\[c\]{@{}l@{}}Desarrolo del sitio web\\ (paginas)\end{tabular}}}                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}1er Parcial}                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}2do Parcial}                                            \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}\[c\]{@{}l@{}}Sitios web (proyecto \\ finalizado)\end{tabular}}}                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}Entrega de Avance}                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{38FFF8}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}Entrega de Avance}                                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{actividades elaboradas}}                                                                               & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{F8FF00}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Fecha de entrega}}                                                                                     & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{FD6864}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Actividades en proceso}}                                                                               & \multicolumn{14}{l|}{\cellcolor\[HTML\]{38FFF8}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: didn't you just ask the same question?

Comment: I corrected him more friend verifies modified code